# How to do http redirect on iis 8?

Tags: url-rewriting, http-redirect

How to redirect a url to another website url on iis 8 ? I tried using http redirect and even url rewriting/ redirecting , but it was not working . At the same time the default website is redirecting to any site when i change the setting on http redirection option of default wabsite.

Comment: Which language? What have you tried? What error / result do you get? You need to provide more info (i.e. example of what you did).

Comment: I want to redirect a url   to spiceworks user portal ,using iis 8 , windows server 2012 . But wen i did http redirecting option , it didnt work. its was giving a connection time out error.... but the default website on iis is getting redirected...

Comment: i did http redirection on iis  and it was not redirecting ... it gave connection time out message... i just need to redirect a given url to a user portal that i have created on spiceworks.